# Form submits via GET not AJAX

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, ajax, validation

This is part of a custom module. I want to validate a frontend form. The validation works; it doesn't submit and it highlights the relevant fields:

[image]

However, if all fields are correctly populated, the form submits via the browser, not AJAX.

My code is in a PHTML template file. The Javascript looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var formId = 'myForm';
    var variableForm = new VarienForm(formId, true);
    function ajaxIfy(theForm) {
        var validify = new Validation(theForm);
        if (validify.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater(
                { success:'formSuccess' },
                '<?php echo $this->getUrl("module/method/post") ?>',
                {
                    method:'post',
                    action:'<?php echo $this->getUrl("module/method/post") ?>',
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json) {
                        Element.hide.delay(3, formId);
                        Element.show('formSuccess');
                    },
                    onLoading:function(request, json){
                        Element.show('formLoader');
                    },
                    parameters:Form.serialize(this)
                }
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Event.observe(variableForm, 'submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ajaxIfy(variableForm);
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

If the form fields are all populated, the form submits in the traditional way, NOT via AJAX. The data appears as a query string append and the request happens as a GET. The form tag is as follows:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" class="module-form">
```

Any help or suggestions would be so appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thanks all for your valuable input; the problem is with the following line:

```
parameters:Form.serialize(this)
```

Should be relevant to this form, like so:

```
parameters: $(formId).serialize(true)
```

Works perfectly now. Source: http://twincreations.co.uk/using-magentos-built-in-ajax-submit-with-validation/

Answer (score 1):

You are mising the form `method="post"`, and will default to GET if not stated.

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Thanks ProxiBlue. Now the form submits via POST, not AJAX :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't instantiate new validator after Varien form instantiation, because it is bundled there already, secondly you not stopping event by preventdefault in that way as you use it. Use e.stop(); instead. Hope it'll helps, it's not I need a full case to replicate an issue.